# Get value of single node yields "... value of Nothing"

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I've got an `XmlNode` object `rowNode`, and when I call `rowNode.OuterXml` I get this result:

```
<Row Nr="1">
  <Område FormulaR1C1="" /> 
  <Position FormulaR1C1="" /> 
  <Lev FormulaR1C1="" /> 
  <Option FormulaR1C1="" /> 
</Row>
```

I'm trying to get the value of `Område` with the following code:

```
rowNode.SelectSingleNode("/Row/Område").InnerText
```

and I get `Referenced object has a value of 'Nothing'.` That's okay, I guess, because it has no value. But then I do it with another turn of the `rowNode` object where the XML is:

```
<Row Nr="2">
  <Område FormulaR1C1="1">1</Område> 
  <Position FormulaR1C1="1">1</Position> 
  <Lev FormulaR1C1="NM">NM</Lev> 
  <Option FormulaR1C1="" /> 
</Row>
```

And I still get `Referenced object has a value of 'Nothing'.` I also tried with some of the other elements - `Lev` and `Position` but I get the same "Nothing" result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about that `å` sign? Can you get the values of the other nodes, like `Position`?

Comment: @Hexaholic , nope, no success. Same "nothing" result.

Comment: Then I'm out. Not a VB expert, it was just a guess.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `rowNode.SelectSingleNode("/Row/Område").InnerText` return `1` given the 2nd XML. Check if your XML document has default namespace (`xmlns="...."`)

Comment: Try this xpath : `.//*[local-name()='Område']`, if that one works then I almost sure the problem was due to default namespace

Comment: @har07 , you last suggestion works. You can post it as answer, so I can accept it. :) And I also checked for namespace setup. There's a place in the code that sets up a namespace, but it's `""`, so... nothing. :D

Comment: @Syspect done converting my comment to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to existence of default namespace. One possible way to access elements in namespace is by using `XmlNamespaceManager`. You need to register mapping of prefix to namespace uri to the namespace manager, and then use the registered prefix properly in the xpath :

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
.....
Dim nsManager As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "your-namespace-uri-here")
Dim result = rowNode.SelectSingleNode("/d:Row/d:Område", nsManager).InnerText
```

Or if you don't need to consider namespaces in selecting the elements, you can just ignore it by using xpath `local-name()` function :

```
Dim result = rowNode.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name()='Row']/*[local-name()='Område']").InnerText
```