# How to select particular node from XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Document xmlns="urn:somethinghere">
        <fapx.001.02>
            <Sts>
                <StsVal>ACCEPTED</StsVal>
            </Sts>
        </fapx.001.02>
    </Document>
```

I want to select value of "StsVal" and for that I wrote this code but getting error:

**Code**

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("myfile.xml")
Dim response As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("Document/fapx.001.02/Sts/StsVal").InnerText
```

**Error**

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**EDIT**

I know I am getting this error due to Nulll value probably because the path I have given in SelectSingleNode function is not correct. That's why I want to know how to give correct path based on given XML.

Comment: Related: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå
I know it is because of Null value because what I don't know how to select that particular node based on the given XML.

Comment: You should **(1)** check if the `doc` is NULL after you've called `doc.Load()` (just to be sure the loading from the file has actually worked), then **(2)** you should use the call to `.SelectSingleNode()` and get the result of that call into a variable and then also check for NULL before accessing its `.InnerText` property....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your XML has default namespace : `xmlns="urn:somethinghere"`.  This topic (XPath query against XML with default namespace) has been asked so many times previously in various forms here in SO. Here are some from my answer history :

1. [Parse XML with succint syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161060/parse-xml-with-succint-syntax/33161230#33161230)
2. [Use XPath with XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396140/use-xpath-with-xml-namespace/25396543#25396543)
3. [Get value of single node yields "... value of Nothing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370946/get-value-of-single-node-yields-value-of-nothing/30371658#30371658)

And this is one possible way to query element in namespace using XPath and `XmlDocument` :

```
Dim nsManager As New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable())
nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "urn:somethinghere")

Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("myfile.xml")
Dim response As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("d:Document/d:fapx.001.02/d:Sts/d:StsVal", nsManager).InnerText
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your document has a default namespace, but the XPath expression doesn't use it. You can pass in a namespace manager and use an alias for the namespace like this:

```
Dim xnm as XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager( doc.NameTable )
xnm.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:somethinghere")
Dim response As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("ns:Document/ns:fapx.001.02/ns:Sts/ns:StsVal", xnm).InnerText
```

My vb's a little rusty, apologies if the syntax needs a little adjustment, but hopefully you get the idea. The "ns" is abritrary, you can use anything you want as a temporary prefix.

It feels like there should be a way of getting it to recognize the default namespace, but for some reason adding the documents nametable on it's own doesn't seem to recognize it, but giving it a name will work.